# Split by whitespace only if not surrounded by [,<,{ or ],>,}

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this one:

```
traceroute <ip-address|dns-name> [ttl <ttl>] [wait <milli-seconds>] [no-dns] [source <ip-address>] [tos <type-of-service>] {router <router-instance>] | all}
```

I'd like to create an array like this:

```
$params = array(
       <ip-address|dns-name>
       [ttl <ttl>]
       [wait <milli-seconds]
       [no-dns]
       [source <ip-address>]
       [tos <tos>]
       {router <router-instance>] | all}
);
```

Should I use `preg_split('/someregex/', $mystring)` ?
Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_match_all` such as:

```
preg_match_all("/\\[[^]]*]|<[^>]*>|{[^}]*}/", $str, $matches);
```

And get your result from the `$matches` array.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative lookarounds. This one uses a negative lookahead for a `<`. This means it will not split if it finds a `<` ahead of the whitespace.

```
$regex='/\s(?!<)/';
$mystring='traceroute <192.168.1.1> [ttl <120>] [wait <1500>] [no-dns] [source <192.168.1.11>] [tos <service>] {router <instance>] | all}';

$array=array();

$array = preg_split($regex, $mystring);

var_dump($array);
```

And my output is

```
array
  0 => string 'traceroute <192.168.1.1>' (length=24)
  1 => string '[ttl <120>]' (length=11)
  2 => string '[wait <1500>]' (length=13)
  3 => string '[no-dns]' (length=8)
  4 => string '[source <192.168.1.11>]' (length=23)
  5 => string '[tos <service>]' (length=15)
  6 => string '{router <instance>]' (length=19)
  7 => string '|' (length=1)
  8 => string 'all}' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, preg_split makes sense and is probably the most efficient way to do this.

Try:

```
preg_split('/[\{\[<](.*?)[>\]\}]/', $mystring);
```

Or if you want to match rather than split, you may want to try:

```
$matches=array();
preg_match('/[\{\[<](.*?)[>\]\}]/',$mystring,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Updated**

I missed that you're trying to get the tokens, not the content of the tokens. I *think* you are going to need to use preg_match. Try something like this one for a good start:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(\{.*?[\}])|(\[.*?\])|(<.*?>)/', $mystring,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <ip-address|dns-name>
        [1] => [ttl <ttl>]
        [2] => [wait <milli-seconds>]
        [3] => [no-dns]
        [4] => [source <ip-address>]
        [5] => [tos <type-of-service>]
        [6] => {router <router-instance>] | all}
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this regex splits on [, ], ... I'd like to split on whitespace only if the two words aren't surrounded by these chars.